# react-native build with xcode 12 on apple M1 (new arm based macbook pro) fails

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-m1

```
    cd /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII

    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/node_modules/.bin:/Users/navalsaini/.jenv/shims:/Users/navalsaini/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/navalsaini/homebrew/bin:/Users/navalsaini/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/navalsaini/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/navalsaini/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/navalsaini/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/navalsaini/.jenv/bin:/Users/navalsaini/Library/Python/3.8/bin:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin"

    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DFBSDKCOCOAPODS=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DGPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DPB_FIELD_32BIT=1 -DPB_NO_PACKED_STRUCTS=1 -DPB_ENABLE_MALLOC=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -index-store-path /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/halfchess-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/halfchess-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/halfchess-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/halfchess-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppAuth -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Bolts -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBLazyVector -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBReactNativeSpec -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKCoreKit -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKLoginKit -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalyticsInterop -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuth -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuthInterop -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseDatabase -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseMessaging -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/GTMAppAuth -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/GTMSessionFetcher -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleDataTransport -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/PromisesObjC -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Protobuf -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTRequired -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNAppleAuthentication -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNCAsyncStorage -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNCMaskedView -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNFirebase -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNGestureHandler -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNGoogleSignin -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNIap -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNReanimated -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNScreens -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNSound -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNStoreReview -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNVectorIcons -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTBlob -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTText -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-perflogger -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/leveldb-library -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/nanopb -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-fbsdk -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-safe-area -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-safe-area-context -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-splash-screen -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources -I/Sources/FBLPromises/include -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/boost-for-react-native -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core -IPods/Headers/Public -IPods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -IPods/Headers/Public/RNReanimated -IPods/Headers/Public/RNFirebase -IPods/Headers/Public/React-RCTBlob -IPods/Headers/Public/FBSDKCoreKit -IPods/Headers/Public/RNGestureHandler -IPods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety -IPods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -IPods/Headers/Public/React-RCTText -IPods/Headers/Public/Yoga -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop -IPods/Headers/Public/React-Core -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore -IPods/Headers/Public/react-native-splash-screen -IPods/Headers/Public/PromisesObjC -IPods/Headers/Public/RNStoreReview -IPods/Headers/Public/GoogleDataTransport -IPods/Headers/Public/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -IPods/Headers/Public/AppAuth -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly -IPods/Headers/Public/FBLazyVector -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuth -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID -IPods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseDatabase -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -IPods/Headers/Public/glog -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -IPods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -IPods/Headers/Public/GTMSessionFetcher -IPods/Headers/Public/react-native-safe-area-context -IPods/Headers/Public/Bolts -IPods/Headers/Public/RNAppleAuthentication -IPods/Headers/Public/FBReactNativeSpec -IPods/Headers/Public/RCTRequired -IPods/Headers/Public/RNGoogleSignin -IPods/Headers/Public/RNIap -IPods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor -IPods/Headers/Public/RNSound -IPods/Headers/Public/Firebase -IPods/Headers/Public/FBSDKLoginKit -IPods/Headers/Public/react-native-safe-area -IPods/Headers/Public/React-perflogger -IPods/Headers/Public/RNCMaskedView -IPods/Headers/Public/RNScreens -IPods/Headers/Public/RNCAsyncStorage -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseMessaging -IPods/Headers/Public/react-native-fbsdk -IPods/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuthInterop -IPods/Headers/Public/leveldb-library -IPods/Headers/Public/nanopb -IPods/Headers/Public/React -IPods/Headers/Public/Protobuf -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalyticsInterop -IPods/Headers/Public/RNVectorIcons -IPods/Headers/Public/GTMAppAuth -IPods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit -IPods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker/ReactCommon -IPods/Headers/Public/React-RCTBlob/RCTBlob -IPods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety/RCTTypeSafety -IPods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion/double-conversion -IPods/Headers/Public/React-RCTText/RCTText -IPods/Headers/Public/Yoga/yoga -IPods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly -IPods/Headers/Public/FBLazyVector/FBLazyVector -IPods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon/ReactCommon -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsi/jsi -IPods/Headers/Public/glog/glog -IPods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact/cxxreact -IPods/Headers/Public/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec -IPods/Headers/Public/RCTRequired/RCTRequired -IPods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor/ReactCommon -IPods/Headers/Public/React-perflogger/reactperflogger -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector/jsinspector -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor/jsireact -IPods/Headers/Public/leveldb-library/leveldb -IPods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/net -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/memory -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/hash -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/lang -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/container -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/detail -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/portability -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/functional -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/net/detail -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/memory/detail -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/ios -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/database -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/instanceid -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/firestore -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/config -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/auth -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/converters -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/admob -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/storage -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/links -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/functions -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/fabric -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/perf -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/messaging -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/notifications -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/analytics -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/fabric/crashlytics -IPods/Headers/Public/Bolts -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current -F/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks -F/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform/Frameworks/Release -F/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UserMessagingPlatform -F/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -fmodule-map-file=/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap -fmodule-map-file=/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.modulemap -fmodule-map-file=/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.modulemap -fmodule-map-file=/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React/React-Core.modulemap -fmodule-map-file=/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.dia -c /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess/AppDelegate.m -o /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
```

```
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess/AppDelegate.h:8:
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
While building module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
In file included from <module-includes>:29:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/string.h:184:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/strings.h:92:
Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/string.h:20:10: fatal error: 'cstdarg' file not found
#include <cstdarg>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess/AppDelegate.h:8:
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <sys/types.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
…
#include <Availability.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
…
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess/AppDelegate.h:8:
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
While building module 'Dispatch' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:20:
While building module 'os_workgroup' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:64:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/os/workgroup.h:29:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/os/workgroup_base.h:8:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <sys/types.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
3 errors generated.
5 errors generated.
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess/AppDelegate.h:8:
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: fatal error: could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess/AppDelegate.h:8:
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
While building module 'ObjectiveC' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:6:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/objc/./runtime.h:27:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/objc/objc.h:31:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <sys/types.h>      // for __DARWIN_NULL
 ~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess/AppDelegate.h:8:
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
While building module 'Security' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:9:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:27:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h:27:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
…
1 error generated.
9 errors generated.
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess/AppDelegate.h:8:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Foundation'
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess/AppDelegate.h:8:
While building module 'CoreGraphics' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIBezierPath.h:10:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBase.h:8:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <stdbool.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
…
1 error generated.
#include <stdbool.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
#include <stdint.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
2 errors generated.
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess/AppDelegate.h:8:
While building module 'FileProvider' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/NSFileProviderExtension.h:15:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/Headers/FileProvider.h:15:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/Headers/NSFileProviderDomain.h:8:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Foundation'
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
While building module 'Crashlytics' imported from /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:165:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Headers/Crashlytics.h:8:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Foundation'
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
28 errors generated.
```

Since there are more than one errors, help would be appreciated on these.

1.

```
Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/string.h:20:10: fatal error: 'cstdarg' file not found
#include <cstdarg>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

2. 

```
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess/AppDelegate.h:8:
While building module 'FileProvider' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/NSFileProviderExtension.h:15:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/Headers/FileProvider.h:15:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/Headers/NSFileProviderDomain.h:8:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Foundation'
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

I will post more updates as I get closer to the solving the build issues on latest MacBook pro, with Xcode 12.4 and react-native.

I was able to build a RN app and run it on simulator. I think this has more to do with libraries that I am using and them having more dependencies than a basic react-native (CRA) app.

Comment: Naval were you able to run the app on m1? If yes can you please help me with the solution as I am facing it too on my end?

Comment: No. I used my alternate laptop to create the app. I am still looking for a solution and will try to solve it soon.

Comment: any solutions for this issue? I am facing the same problem